# Converting .lite to. tflite format

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, voice-recognition, keyword-spotting, tflite

Currently, I am evaluating Edge Impulse platform & generated .lite model.

Can anyone please guide me how to convert the .lite model to. tflite?

Answer (score 0):

The `.lite` file is already a TFLite file. Just rename to `.tflite`.